# What if people have different opinion about the question's closure?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I recently asked a [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24670/what-is-intention-of-dr-lanning-in-i-robot), It was commented to re-alter the way it is posted and change the title of the question by the moderator. It has different opinion on its closure. So i believe based on the votes the Question will be re-opened. Or is it like moderators decision.?

How many votes are needed for the question to be re-opened?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It takes 5 votes to close a question. It takes the same to reopen a question. If there's disagreement, we discuss it on meta, and usually a moderator acts according to the community's decision (if there is a clear community decision).

Votes by [moderators](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) (users with a ♦ after their name) are immediately binding. Users with a gold tag badge can also close and reopen questions with that tag with a single vote, but only for closure as duplicates.

The question looks ok to me now, I cast the final reopen vote.